# github deleted files on computer

Tags: github

So I'm trying to learn how to use GitHub... now my computer's out of whack.

fooled around with a folder - `c:/documents/class/lab1part1`, typed `git init` for that folder. Couldn't upload, made some mistakes.
Changed folder to `c:/documents/class/lab2part3` and ran `git init`. made mistakes.
Went back to `c:/documents/class/`, was able to successfully upload (`git init, git add, etc`).
Went to github.com and all folders and files were there... except for folders (with files in it) `lab1part1` and `lab2part3`.
So, I deleted that repository and started all over again...
Googled, one site said to use the command "`rm -rf $HOME/.git`" to undo the `git init` on my folder.
I typed that in git bash... and things went to hell.

This was done on a macbook pro that dual boots OSX and Windows 10 (clearly this occurred on the windows partition).
Right now - I'm unable to access the start menu, my programs that were in the task bar are gone, I'm unable to access connect to a network or any of my files.

What happened, and how to I fix this - i cannot afford to lose my labs!!!!

Comment: You should know what you are doing before typing `rm -rf`. The default Windows answer: Re-install windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside the `rm -rf` step:

- your `lab1part1` and `lab2part3` were not on GitHub because you create a git repo in their parent folder `c:/documents/class/`: when you pushed that repo, the two subfolders were recorded as **nested** git repo **[gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))
- as long as those folders are on your local machine, you will be able to add, commit and push once again (but you will need to push to two separate GitHub repos)

So save your folders elsewhere (backup), re-install Windows, and try agian.